# Symfony controller as a service not working

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, controller

I have this controller:

```
<?php

namespace DnD\RaHApiBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;

class testController extends Controller
{

  private $agentRepository;

  public function __construct(AgentRepository $agentRepository)
  {
    $this->agentRepository = $agentRepository;
  }


  public function getall()
  {
    return "asdf";
  }

}
```

This routing.yml:

```
test:
  path: /test
  defaults: {_controller: test_controller:getall}
```

And this services.yml

```
agent_repository:
        class: Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
        factory_service: doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager
        factory_method: getRepository
        arguments:
            - DnD\RaHApiBundle\Entity\Agent


test:
        class: DnD\RaHApiBundle\Controller\testController
        arguments: ["@agent_repository"]
```

I'm developing an API with fosrestbundle. Whenever I hit this url: /test, I get back the following error:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to DnD\RaHApiBundle\Controller\testController::__construct() must be an instance of DnD\RaHApiBundle\Controller\AgentRepository, instance of DnD\RaHApiBundle\Repository\AgentRepository given, called in /Users/danielrvt/IdeaProjects/rentahouse/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 2525 and defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add `use` statement in the controller.

```
use DnD\RaHApiBundle\Repository\AgentRepository;
```

Comment: I would like to say that the error is very extrange... I couldn't figure that out...

Comment: Sorry, i dont know what does extrange mean. When you omit use statement on any class and use namespace PHP appends that namespace to any class located in the code except ones defined in `use` statement. Thats why `AgentRepository` in the constructor's parameter becomes `DnD\RaHApiBundle\Controller\AgentRepository`

Comment: It's true for classes that don't have explicit namespace identifiers. `\\` is also a namespace identifier which points to root namespace.